# MYSQL how to query out current balance as previous balance

Tags: mysql

I need to make a query with the expected result as below. Consider the prev. Balance is auto-calculated field. And i want to populate with MYSQL query by taking the Balance (from previous row) see picture. How to query out using mysql? The date can be any date not sequential and that below is just an illustration.

Note that the previous balance is just a sequence of the old balance. Meaning that the first previous balance always null or zero and the balance get its amount from added amount. From the first balance the second record start to have its previous balance and it goes on and on

[image]

Comment: What's the mysql version?

Comment: It's mariadb i am not exactly sure the version

Comment: Very confusing please post expected output and what you've tried so far.

Comment: The question is straight forward but the solution is very tricky i couldn't really figure out how to do this yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like i have thought this too far....after looking back the query is quite simple it's just that the idea was difficult to grasp in the first place. This query will solve the problem and calculate both balance and previous balance. It it called running balance / cumulative balance. The idea is the inner query will calculate the previous balance first...once the previous balance is obtain then use it to calculate balance in the outer query

```
SELECT 
  t2.date,
  t2.added_amount,
  t2.previous_balance
  t2.previous_balance + t2.added_amount AS balance

FROM      

(Select 
   t.date,
   t.added_amount,
   (SELECT sum(t1.added_amount) FROM table t1
    WHERE t1.date < t.date) as previous_balance
FROM table t
   ORDER BY t.date) t2

ORDER BY t2.date
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `row_number()` to be used for `left join` your `previous balance`.

```
select t1.*, t2.PrevBalance from
    (select Date, PrevBalance, AddedAmount,
        row_number() over (order by Date asc) as rn 
    from tableA) t1    
left join 
    (select Date, PrevBalance, AddedAmount,
        row_number() over (order by Date asc) as rn 
    from tableA) t2 on t2.rn + 1 = t1.rn
```

Comment: I think you get it wrong idea...i want to balance as previous balance...it is not as straightforward as that

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to compute the previous balance from the current balance, then a substraction is enough:

```
select 
    date,
    balance - added_amount prev_balance,
    added_amount,
    balance
from mytable
```

Note: you mentionned that `balance` is some kind of computed column. Please note that, if you are running MySL 8.0, you can compute both balance and prev balance with window functions:

```
select
    date,
    coalesce(
        sum(added_amount) over(
            order by date
            rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
        ),
    0) prev_balance,
    added_amount,
    sum(added_amount) over(order by date) balance
from mytable
```

This is somewhat more flexible than storing values in the table itself.

Comment: That is very good idea ...wow i never thought of it lol...but the point is the balance is also auto-calculated which comes from previous balance

Comment: Actually the previous balance and balance both computed value...its like the first balance become the previous balance and so on and on and on