# MySQL - update column values based on changes in one row

Tags: mysql

I need to update the amount paid and balance amount values based on the changes in the any of the row.

**My table:**

```
prev_bal tot_amnt net_pay paid bal_amnt date
10        100      110     10  100      13/04/2020
100       100      200      0  200      14/04/2020
```

**Expected Result:**

```
prev_bal   tot_amnt    net_pay paid  bal_amnt     date
    10        100      110      100    10          13/04/2020
    10       100       110       0    110         14/04/2020
```

if i update for the date 13/04/2020 paid as 10,so have to update bal_amnt and prev_bal to all the dates.How to achieve this in mysql.

Comment: Are you looking for a running/cumulative total ? Can you add expected result please.

Comment: @P.Salmon Yes i need running/cumulative values. can you check my updated question.

Comment: It's not obvious how the balance amount or previous balance is calculated  - which columns are used in the calculation?

Comment: prev_bal is previous of the bal_amnt col. net_pay is  tot_amnt+prev_bal . bal_amnt is  net_pay - paid.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MYSQL how to query out current balance as previous balance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58833270/mysql-how-to-query-out-current-balance-as-previous-balance)